# Mobile Responsive Javascript Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I've been working on this [data map](https://www.shiftins.com/county/index.html) and trying to make it more mobile responsive. The problem is now I cant seem to figure out how to change the point at which it becomes responsive.

This is the smallest point at which the map is properly scaled
[image]

If I move it in 1 more pixel, it re-sizes like this
[image]

How can I set the re-size boundary to within 10-20 pixels of the content?
[image]

Comment: Well you need to append your chart elements to a single svg whose width and height you need to calculate dynamically and from the calculated width and height of svg give width and heights to 3 inner charts .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use raw [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)  to fix this issue, i tried to show you how you can solve but you know how you structured so its just dummy.

did you see the (min-width: 500px) that's the point you wanna set.

```
<div class="min-range-1">
 map goes here 
</div>

<div class="min-range-2">
charts goes here 
</div>


<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
/* For tablets: */
.min-range-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.min-range-2 {width: 16.66%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.min-range-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.min-range-2 {width: 16.66%;} 
}
```

Comment: Actually I didn't build the map. My developer has been slacking and I've been stuck trying to figure this part out. Can you please be a bit more specific... Sorry I'm not a developer. I assume I add this to the .css file right?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code under `windows resize` and add your charts to a single `parent id` so that rest all will be calculated dynamically without any break.

```
  var containerWidth = $("#yourChartId").parent().width(); // gets immediate parent width
  var containerheight = $("#yourChartId").parent().height();// gets immediate parent height

     // Give the below to parent svg
     var margin = {top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20, left: 40},
     width = containerWidth- margin.left - margin.right,
     height = containerheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     // Assign below widths and heights to respective children

    var marginMap = {top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 10, left: 20}
    widthMap = width/2 - marginMap.left - marginMap.right,
    heightMap = height/2 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

    var marginBargraphs = {top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 10, left: 20}
    widthBargraphs = width/2 - marginBargraphs.left - marginBargraphs.right,
    heightBargraphs = height/2 - marginBargraphs.top - marginBargraphs.bottom;
```

Comment: I have been unable to implement your changes. Would you be interested in allowing me to hire you to complete the task?

Comment: Sure can you share more details.

Comment: please reach out to me by emailing greasy@gmail.com.